# jQuery highlighting clicked list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When I clicked on list item it is highlighting only one. If list item has sub list then the total sub list is also highlighting but only one list should be highlight.

**CSS**

```
.active {
  background: #f00;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="orgCat">
  <li class="list-group-item active">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus
    <ul>
    <li>abc</li>
    <li>sdf</li>
    <li>oupu
      <ul>
      <li>progf</li>
      <li>ghfhg</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('#orgCat li').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    $that = $(this);

    $that.parent().find('li').removeClass('active');
    $that.addClass('active');
  });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mgjk3xk2/204/)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What the problem?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What do you want ti implement ?

Comment: well you set the background color of the li and the li has children so of course the children will have the same background....

Comment: @HemaNandagopal check updated question.

Comment: @epascarello it should be highlight only one.

Comment: BUT the children are in the li that you are setting the background color too..... The children will inherit the color of the parent.

Comment: Yes, That is the problem which I am facing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `return false` like this:

```
$('#orgCat li').click(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

$that=$(this);
$('#orgCat .active').removeClass('active');
$that.addClass('active');
return false;
});
```

```js
$('#orgCat li').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
   $that=$(this);
    $('#orgCat .active').removeClass('active');
    $that.addClass('active');
    return false;
  });
```

```css
.active {
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="orgCat">
  <li class="list-group-item active">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus
    <ul>
    <li>abc</li>
    <li>sdf</li>
    <li>oupu
      <ul>
      <li>progf</li>
      <li>ghfhg</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<span>` tag in li

HTML:

```
 <ul id="orgCat">
  <li class="list-group-item"><span class='active'>Cras justo odio</span></li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><span>Dapibus ac facilisis in</span></li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><span>Morbi leo risus</span>
    <ul>
    <li><span>abc</span></li>
    <li><span>sdf</span></li>
    <li>oupu
      <ul>
      <li><span>progf</span></li>
      <li><span>ghfhg</span></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><span>Porta ac consectetur ac</span></li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><span>Vestibulum at eros</span></li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><span>Cras justo odio</span></li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><span>Dapibus ac facilisis in</span></li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><span>Morbi leo risus</span></li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><span>Porta ac consectetur ac</span></li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><span>Vestibulum at eros</span></li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
 $('#orgCat li span').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $that = $(this);    
   $('li span').removeClass('active');
    $that.addClass('active');
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understand you correctly, you want something more like this:

```
$(function(){
  $(document).on('click', 'li', function(e) {
    var $me = $(e.originalEvent.target);
    e.preventDefault();
    $('li.active').removeClass('active');
    $me.addClass('active'); 
    $('#out').text($me.text());
  });
});
```

[see fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/theredhead/um4n9mak/)

Answer (score 1):

Try using an element around the text like below, here I've used span

```js
$('#orgCat span').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
```

```css
.active {
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-a23g1Nt4dtEYOj7bR+vTu7+T8VP13humZFBJNIYoEJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<ul id="orgCat">
  <li class="list-group-item"><span class="active">Cras justo odio</span></li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><span>Dapibus ac facilisis in</span></li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><span>Morbi leo risus</span>
    <ul>
    <li><span>abc</span></li>
    <li><span>sdf</span></li>
    <li><span>oupu</span>
      <ul>
      <li><span>progf</span></li>
      <li><span>ghfhg</span></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><span>Porta ac consectetur ac</span></li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><span>Vestibulum at eros</span></li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><span>Cras justo odio</span></li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><span>Dapibus ac facilisis in</span></li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><span>Morbi leo risus</span></li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><span>Porta ac consectetur ac</span></li>
  <li class="list-group-item"><span>Vestibulum at eros</span></li>
</ul>
```